# Updating separate Tkinter canvases with different images simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm working on a Tkinter application that involves displaying real-time video feed on multiple canvases. Each canvas should display a different image received from different sources. However, I'm facing difficulties in updating the canvases with the respective images simultaneously.

Here's a simplified version of my code:
python

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.canvas1 = tk.Canvas(self.root)
        self.canvas2 = tk.Canvas(self.root)
        self.tk_photo1 = None
        self.tk_photo2 = None
  ### rest of code #####
    def update_canvas(self):
        while True:
            if not self.current_frame is None and self.camera_on.get():
                img_aruco, [xA, yA, zA, _, _, _] = self.aruco_decetor.start_aruco(self.current_frame)
                img_mine, [xM, yM, zM] = self.mine_decetor.start_mine(self.current_frame, self.depth_image)
                rgb_frame_A = cv2.cvtColor(img_aruco, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                rgb_frame_M = cv2.cvtColor(img_mine, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                img1 = Image.fromarray(rgb_frame_A)
                img2 = Image.fromarray(rgb_frame_M)
                ####root.after_idle(lambda img1=img1, img2=img2:[self.tk_photo1.paste(img1),self.tk_photo2.paste(img2)])
                root.after_idle(lambda img1=img1: self.tk_photo1.paste(img1))
                root.after_idle(lambda img2=img2: self.tk_photo2.paste(img2))
            time.sleep(0.01)  # Add small delay between updates


root = tk.Tk()
app = MyApp(root)
app.update_canvas()
root.mainloop()
```

The issue I'm facing is that both canvases are being updated with the same image, even though img1 and img2 are different. It seems like the self.tk_photo1 and self.tk_photo2 variables are not being updated correctly within the update_canvas method.I have tried using lambda functions and passing the images as arguments to the after_idle method, but it didn't resolve the issue.How can I update the canvases with the respective images simultaneously? I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me resolve this problem. Thank you!

```
self.canvas1.config(image=self.tk_photo1)
self.canvas2.config(image=self.tk_photo2)
```

```
self.canvas1.create_image(0, 0, image=self.tk_photo1, anchor=tk.NW)
self.canvas2.create_image(0, 0, image=self.tk_photo2, anchor=tk.NW)
```

`root.after_idle(lambda img1=img1, img2=img2: [self.tk_photo1.paste(img1), self.tk_photo2.paste(img2)])`

```
root.after_idle(lambda imgA=img1: self.tk_photo1.paste(imgA))
root.after_idle(lambda imgM=img2: self.tk_photo2.paste(imgM))
```

Comment: line 14, in update_canvas
    if not self.current_frame is None and self.camera_on.get():
AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'current_frame'

Comment: Your Tags didn't mention opencv

Comment: this is a simplified code not full

Comment: i solved but i didnt know why
i gave each frame a copy from the frame current_frame 
and it worked but i dont know why cause my code 2 classes aruco and mine doesn't process on the main image